# Loading tables in R with space seperation

Tags: r, statistics, loading

How to load a space seperated table with spaces inside the fields?

Simple case data:

```
Grade Area School Goals
4 Rural Elm Popular
4 Rural Elm Sports
4 Rural Elm Grades
4 Rural Elm Popular
3 Rural Brentwood Elementary Sports
3 Suburban Ridge Popular
```

Notice how the last element has space seperation in naming the school("Brentwood Elementary" as opposed to "Elm")

The following query fails with: "line x did not have y elements"

```
dat = read.table("dat.txt",header=TRUE)
```

Edit:
The data points are all factors and contains a set values

Edit: full data available through http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/DASL/Datafiles/PopularKids.html
Thanks to @AmandaMahto

Comment: What are the unique values in the Area and Goals column?  Does those columns have more than one word?

Comment: @user3711518  I meant do you have words like `Sub urban` for the second column and 4th?

Comment: Area: Rural, Suburban, or Urban
Goals: Popular, Sports, Grade

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yes, it is, thanks for digging it up.

Comment: work around: copy paste to http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/app/ and wrangle/ export csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is pretty much "It depends on how much you know about the data set."

For instance, in the description for the dataset, it specifies the possible values for each variable. Here, we know that there are only a few schools with multi-word names, and that these follow a predictable pattern of "Elementary" and "Middle".

As such, you could read the data in using `readLines` and figure out the least obtrusive way to insert a delimiter before re-reading the data with `read.table`.

Here's an example:

Sample data:

```
cat("Grade Area School Goals Value",
    "4 Rural Elm Popular 1",
    "4 Rural Elm Sports 2",
    "4 Rural Elm Grades 1",
    "4 Rural Elm Popular 3",
    "3 Rural Brentwood Elementary Sports 4",
    "3 Rural Brentwood Middle Grades 3",
    "3 Suburban Ridge Popular 3", sep = "\n", file = "test.txt")
```

Read it in as a character vector:

```
x <- readLines("test.txt")
```

Use `gsub` to force the multi-word school names to become a single word (separated by an underscore). Then, use `read.table` to get your `data.frame`.

```
read.table(text = gsub(" (Elementary|Middle)", "_\\1", x), header = TRUE)
#   Grade     Area               School   Goals Value
# 1     4    Rural                  Elm Popular     1
# 2     4    Rural                  Elm  Sports     2
# 3     4    Rural                  Elm  Grades     1
# 4     4    Rural                  Elm Popular     3
# 5     3    Rural Brentwood_Elementary  Sports     4
# 6     3    Rural     Brentwood_Middle  Grades     3
# 7     3 Suburban                Ridge Popular     3
```

Comment: Or replace it with single quotes for a multi-word

Comment: @akrun, Yeah. I suppose that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you can use the data source Ananda found, it's pretty easy since the `<pre>` area is tab delimited:

```
library(rvest)

pg <- html("http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/DASL/Datafiles/PopularKids.html")
dat <- pg %>% html_nodes("pre") %>% html_text() 
dat <-  read.table(text=dat, sep="\t", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat[245:249,]

##     Gender Grade Age  Race Urban.Rural       School   Goals Grades Sports Looks Money
## 245   girl     4   9 White       Rural         Sand  Grades      1      3     2     4
## 246   girl     4   9 White       Rural         Sand  Sports      3      2     1     4
## 247   girl     4   9 White       Rural         Sand  Sports      3      2     1     4
## 248   girl     4   9 White       Rural         Sand  Grades      2      1     3     4
## 249   girl     6  12 White       Rural Brown Middle Popular      4      2     1     3
```

To actually answer your question (this is a bit like Ananda's answer) you'll need to know where the problem column is and work around it. This one uses `gsubfn` and pre-defined values for that column to make whole then split afterwards:

```
library(gsubfn)

# awful.txt is here https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/13cee15c91fdadb10fbc

lines <- readLines("awful.txt")

schools <- c("Brentwood Elementary", "Brentwood Middle", "Brown Middle", "Westdale Middle")
expr <- paste("(", paste(schools, collapse="|"), ")", sep="")
lines <- gsubfn(expr, function(x) { gsub(" ", "_", x) }, lines)

dat <- read.table(text=paste(lines, sep="", collapse="\n"), 
                  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat$School <- gsub("_", " ", dat$School)

dat[c(1,34,94,198,255,324,377,433),]

##     Gender Grade Age  Race Urban.Rural               School   Goals Grades Sports Looks Money
## 1      boy     5  11 White       Rural                  Elm  Sports      1      2     4     3
## 34     boy     4  10 White    Suburban Brentwood Elementary  Grades      2      1     3     4
## 94    girl     6  11 White    Suburban     Brentwood Middle  Grades      3      4     1     2
## 198    boy     5  10 White       Rural                Ridge  Sports      4      2     1     3
## 255   girl     6  12 Other       Rural         Brown Middle  Grades      3      2     1     4
## 324    boy     4   9 Other       Urban                 Main  Grades      4      1     3     2
## 377    boy     4   9 White       Urban              Portage Popular      4      1     2     3
## 433   girl     6  11 White       Urban      Westdale Middle Popular      4      2     1     3
```

Comment: (+1) I just pasted it into a text editor and realized that it is tab-delimited too. It wasn't obvious from looking at the source.

Comment: Someone already CSV'd it too https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall11/sta101.02/labs/popular.csv

Comment: gosh this should be in an R data package somewhere :-)

Comment: And Google Spreadsheeted it too: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkY2lFgS9uiDdDdxazdLMnUwalpyMjc0UlY1U2p4cnc#gid=0